# Conditional Formatting with 2 formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting, conditional-statements

I'm trying to conditional format a cell.

I have an amount in C3 (32,123.45). I have a total formula in column K (column K is totaling C9, E9, I9, J9 etc). There is a formula that is C3-K9-K13-K17-K23. The result should be $51, 123.45. Since the formatting is Accounting, it is showing ($17,123.45) instead of the $51,123.45.

I would like to use the conditional formatting so that if the result of the range (C3-K9-K13-K17-K23) is higher than C3, then it should format red. I'm having trouble with this as I'm not that good with excel. This seems to be an easy fix. Just can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With C3 Selected go to Conditional Formatting > New rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format and enter this formula.

=SUM($C$3,$K$9,$K$13,$K$17,$K$23)>$C$3

Click "format..." and pick how you want the cell to look when it is higher than the range.

As an aside, your formatting won't change your value. Your calculation is $68,246.90 too low.

Comment: OMG! I'm so excited someone answered. I will try this right now and let you know. Thank you!!

Comment: IT WORKED!! Ok so now... is there a way to... if the result is greater than C3 red or lower green. Is there a way to use the conditional formatting in the same cell/formula for that?

Comment: There is, follow the same steps to put in a second formula: =SUM($C$3,$K$9,$K$13,$K$17,$K$23)<$C$3 and format the cell as usual.

If the answer worked could you please accept the answer and up vote? it would help me out immensely.

Comment: It worked but adding the second formula, it isn't working like I want it to display.

Comment: What specifically is wrong? I'm happy to help walk you through any issues you run into.